# change stream name on runtime on wowza

Tags: streaming, http-live-streaming, wowza, broadcasting, wowza-transcoder

I have one question regarding sending stream to TV using wowza.

I need to send multiple streams running at same time to TV station with using one link
Basically question is that, I have multiple streams with different name and when i need to send to TV it convert to one unique name on run-time.

Is this possible ? if yes please explain bit more..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sending to "TV" you mean leveraging Push Publish to send to an external CDN or Wowza Server, then you can specify the outbound stream name within the Push Publish [mapping](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?109#aboutmapfile) by setting the "streamName" parameter.  You could also remap the inbound published stream name via the approach found [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?157-How-to-override-publish-to-remap-a-stream-name).

Otherwise, if you are referring to requests made for a particular stream on your given Wowza Instance (vs pushing outbound), then you could leverage the [Stream Name Alias](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?116-How-to-get-the-StreamNameAlias-AddOn) module of which you could map any stream name to another.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: thanks for reply @Matt, i want to ask you one thing.. mapping of streams name is possible by wowza end ? means  server side

Comment: @NeerajSharma - For example: if a stream is published as "myStream" but you want subsequent playback requests to access under the name "testStream" then you can do this by using stream name alias module as mentioned above (see link).

Comment: got it man.. thanks alot... is this possible by programmatically  in php ?

Comment: target stream name change by particular stream name programmatically ?

Comment: You could build an HTTP Provider - [link](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?762-How-to-use-server-side-modules-and-HTTP-Providers) - and then query it via your external php script..  The source also comes with the stream name alias module for you to further manipulate.